# Trying to enter Date/String in ChartDataEntry

Tags: ios, swift, charts, swiftcharts

I am trying to add a Date/String as the xAxis labels in [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) (needs to have equal space in between labels)

I am doing below but the x in the constructor only expects a double.

Any idea?

```
for i in 0..<self.grahEntries.count {
     let x1 = self.grahEntries[i].x
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
     let date = dateFormatter.date(from: x1)
     print(date)
     let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: date, y: self.grahEntries[i].y)//HERE IS MY PROBLEM!! xAxis is only double
     dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}

 let line1 = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Consumed")
    line1.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    line1.mode = .cubicBezier
    line1.cubicIntensity = 0.2


    let gradient = getGradientFilling()
    line1.fill = Fill.fillWithLinearGradient(gradient, angle: 90.0)
    line1.drawFilledEnabled = true

    let data = LineChartData()
    data.addDataSet(line1)
    mChart.data = data
    mChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
    mChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 1.5)

    mChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateAxisValueFormatter()
    mChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0


    mChart.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false
    mChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    mChart.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    mChart.leftAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
    mChart.leftAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    mChart.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    mChart.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    mChart.legend.enabled = false
    mChart.xAxis.enabled = true
    mChart.leftAxis.enabled = true
    mChart.rightAxis.enabled = false

    mChart.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    mChart.xAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    mChart.xAxis.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true
    mChart.xAxis.avoidFirstLastClippingEnabled = true
```

UPDATE  :

I did as @ces said its spreading them accurately but I still cant see labels. I updated my code above to show table
[image]

Comment: What is the type of  `y`?

Comment: @vadian y is double type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the data to be spaced evenly (i.e. not representing an accurate timeline) then the answer is simpler.

Change your `for` loop to

```
var dates: [String] = []
for i in 0..<self.grahEntries.count {
     let x1 = self.grahEntries[i].x
     let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
     dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
     let date = dateFormatter.date(from: x1)
     dates.append(date)
     let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: self.grahEntries[i].y)
     dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
}
```

and change

```
mChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateAxisValueFormatter(dates)
```

Then change `DataAxisValueFormatter` to accept an array of strings in the constructor and store them. Change

```
func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
{
    let i = Int(value)
    return dates[i]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, you'll need to use a double (or numeric value) as the value for x. Where I've plotted this against dates before, my method has been to convert the date to a numeric by using the seconds since the epoch and converting to days, using:-

```
 date.timeIntervalSince1970 / secondsPerDay
```

where (accurate enough):-

```
let secondsPerDay = 24.0 * 3600.0
```

To format the date on the axis for the viewer, I then use a formatter such as this:-

```
class DateAxisValueFormatter : NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter
{
  let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

  override init()
  {
    super.init()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM"
  }

  func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String
  {
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value * secondsPerDay)
    return dateFormatter.string(from: date)
  }
}
```

Which converts the value I've used back into the correct text. If you set

```
lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = DateAxisValueFormatter()
lineChart.xAxis.granularity = 1.0
```

then you'll only see days on the bottom.

So in summary:

- Find a numeric conversion for the date.
- Use this for the value
- Convert back to a date in the formatter.

Comment: Thx! it split the xAxis up nicley but I cant see label on bottom(see above code). Also what if I wanted to split up the xAxis equally and not by date?

Comment: mChart.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false - does that stop labels too?

Comment: line1.axisDependency = .left

Comment: The screen capture shows the graph not completing at the bottom, i.e. the left axis doesn't seem to close nicely. Are you sure the view is fully on the screen?

Comment: I hard coded 1 it works. I am doing this.      let dateseconds = date!.timeIntervalSince1970 / secondsPerDay
            
            let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x:dateseconds, y: self.grahEntries[i].y)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189155/discussion-between-ces-and-user1163234).